# Open source alternatives to mapbox-gl?

Tags: vector-tiles, mapbox-gl-js

What are the alternative vector tiles pipeline tools (producing -> rendering) to mapbox-gl as it is no longer open-source starting from its version 2.0.0?

[image: Mapgbox-gl]

Source: https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#200

Comment: For software recommendations there is the [softwarerecs.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 5):

MapLibre GL JS seems a serious fork currently.

https://github.com/maplibre/maplibre-gl-js

Answer (score 4):

There are two open source forks of Mapbox GL libraries:

- For javascript [Maplibre GL JS](https://github.com/maplibre/maplibre-gl-js)
- For Android and iOS [Maplibre GL Native](https://github.com/maptiler/maplibre-gl-native)

Answer (score 2):

[OpenMapTiles](https://openmaptiles.org) comes to my mind, although it's questionable if one really wants to run the whole "producing" pipeline oneself as it is quite time and resource consuming.

MapBox GL JS was mostly for the rendering part, and there are alternatives:

[OpenLayers](https://openlayers.org) also supports rendering vector tiles, an example is available [here](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/mapbox-vector-tiles.html), with [more examples](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/) available (search for "Vector").